# How to access dragged object fields in react drag and drop?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

So basically I'm trying to use dnd in a simple game, but i feel like i don't quite understand the point of some params. I have two components being used as a source and target. The source is receiving a unit prop from the parent and i'd like the Field component(target) to know which unit is being dragged atm and after the drop display it inside it. I've seen i can specify some fields in beginDrag(), but i think it may not be it. Is is possible or is there a workaround?

```
const BenchTileSource = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    // Return the data describing the dragged item
    const item = { unit: props.unit };
    return item;
  }
};

const TileBackground = styled.div`
    ...
`;

function UnitBenchTile({ unit }) {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { type: TileTypes.BENCH_TILE },
    collect: monitor => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
    })
  });
  return unit ? (
    <TileBackground ref={drag}>{unit.name}</TileBackground>
  ) : (
    <TileBackground />
  );
}

export default BenchTileSource(
  TileTypes.BENCH_TILE,
  BenchTileSource
)(UnitBenchTile);


import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { TileTypes } from "../dragTypes/TileTypes";
import { useDrop } from "react-dnd";

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    currentPosition: state.currentPosition,
    unitsPositions: state.unitsPositions
  };
};

  ...

function Field({ index, children, dispatch }) {
  const unitsPositions = useSelector(
    state => state.unitsPositionsReducer.unitsPositions
  );

  const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: TileTypes.BENCH_TILE,
    drop: monitor => setCurrentPosition([x, y], monitor.getItem()),
    collect: monitor => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
      item: monitor.item
    })
  });

  const setCurrentPosition = (newPosition, unit) => {
    if (!unitsPositions[index].unit) {
      const result = unitsPositions;
      result[index] = { position: newPosition, unit: unit };
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_UNITS_POSITIONS", result });
    }
  };

  const isRight = (index - 9) % 10 === 0;
  const isBottom = index >= 50;
  const x = index % 10;
  const y = Math.floor(index / 6);

  if (isRight && isBottom)
    return <FrameBottomRight ref={drop}>{children}</FrameBottomRight>;
  else if (isRight) return <FrameRight ref={drop}>{children}</FrameRight>;
  else if (isBottom) return <FrameBottom ref={drop}>{children}</FrameBottom>;
  else return <Frame ref={drop}>{children}</Frame>;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Field);
```

Comment: I think you may specify more your problem, that's a lot of abstraction around your post, make it simplier

Comment: To put it more simple: Can i pass some arguments( for example {unit: unit}) from drag source when starting to drag, in such a way that the drop target object gets those arguments after the successful drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information that is needed can be accessed by the monitors of react-dnd. In this case, you want to access the currently dragged source in the target so you have to make use of the DropTargetMonitor's method `getItem()` and it will return all the properties defined in the `item` property of the dragged source. No need to supply additional fields when a drag operation begins if you already have an `id` defined in your item, that field is enough to identify which item is being dragged.

**UPDATE**
if you really want to pass additional fields, you can simply merge the item data by "spreading" it to a new object together with your additional data in your begin method.

```
return {
  ...monitor.item,
  additional: data
}
```

Comment: The problem is that even if i specify {unit:props.unit} in beginDrag I'm still getting undefined after calling getItem on dropTarget side.

Comment: In general answer is correct, but the only note: specify argument inside useDrag item. But anyway, thanks a lot!